# How to auto start a mac with socks server on using ssh?

Tags: macos, networking, mac, ssh, proxy

There are a number of tutorials online that teach to use ssh as a socks5 server, after sshd is up, the next step is to have a terminal open, then open a socks5 server port by typing something like the following

```
ssh -D8080 -g localhost -l <username>
```

I would like my mac to auto start with 8080 port opened as socks5 server, how should I achieve this?

Answer (score -1):

Try to start this script in LaunchDaemons. `sudo launchctl load` allow you to manage and inspect daemons.